# Creating a windows service from a windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application, I wonder how can I modify a windows service from that application.
This application windows forms will configure some parameters for this windows service.

Example: 
Could have a button that would set this windows service with some parameters.

Thanks,

Rodrigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a service by setting the startup parameters through the form application using ServiceController class which will be available under the namespace System.ServiceProcess.

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController();
string[] args=new string[2];
args[0] = "Your first argument";
args[1] = "Your second argument";
service.DisplayName = "Your Service Display Name";//As it appears in services.msc
service.Start(args);
```

Comment: Hi, Step where the service name?

Comment: If you the know the service name then you can give service.ServiceName else give the service.DisplayName which appears in the Services.msc. Note: DisplayName and ServiceName are different.

Comment: In my case the service already exists. I stop the service and start it again with the new parameters.